# Collision of etoolbox and LuaLatex

Tags: luatex, etoolbox, luacode

I use a macro `\mychoice{item a, item b, items c,…}` that returns one of the  items of the comma-separated-list determined by an external counter based on the `\docsvlist` macro from `etoolbox`. In simple text, this macro works fine, but when I try to use it in a `\directlua{}` from Lua(La)TeX, it raises strange (at least for me) errors.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{luacode*}
 function dummy(argument)
 end
\end{luacode*}

\newcounter{choicecounter}
\newcounter{argcounter}

\newcommand{\mychoice}[1]{
    \setcounter{argcounter}{0}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{
        \stepcounter{argcounter}
        \csedef{argcounter\arabic{argcounter}}{##1}}
    \docsvlist{#1}
    \csuse{argcounter\arabic{choicecounter}}
}

\newcommand{\main}[1]{%
    \setcounter{choicecounter}{#1}
    hello world \mychoice{one,{two,three}}
    \directlua{dummy(\luastring{\mychoice{foo,bar}})}
}

\begin{document}
\main{1}

\main{2}
\end{document}
```

So this version raises the error. If you comment out the `\directlua` it compiles fine.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a bug somewhere?

PS: Replacing `\directlua` with `\luadirect` or `\luaexec` from `luacode`-package or leaving out `\luastring`-command doesn't change anything.

Comment: your command is not expandable. You can't fed abitrary stuff to directlua, it must expand to something lua can handle.

Comment: And how can I make it expandable? Or rather: What is preventing it from being expanded to something, lua can handle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use expl3 and `\clist_item:nn` to select an item in a list. This is expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{luacode*}
 function dummy(argument)
  tex.sprint("lua: ".. argument)
 end
\end{luacode*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\main}[1]{%
    hello~world~\clist_item:nn{one,{two,three}}{#1}\par
    \directlua{dummy(\luastring{\clist_item:nn{foo,bar}{#1}})}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\main{1}

\main{2}
\end{document}
```

As egreg suggested in the comments an real expl3 version would use \lua_now:e instead of \directlua:

```
 \lua_now:e {dummy("\lua_escape:e{\clist_item:nn{foo,bar}{#1}}")}
```

[image]

Comment: `\lua_now:e {dummy("\lua_escape:e{\clist_item:nn{foo,bar}{#1}}")}`

Comment: @egreg yes, but perhaps this looks to frightening for someone not used to expl3 ;-) (but I added it).

Comment: That's not such a good idea.  `expl3` takes ages to load in LuaTeX because of the huge Unicode tables.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86783/discussion-on-answer-by-ulrike-fischer-collision-of-etoolbox-and-lualatex).

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer . This answer is doing exactly what I want. I didn't think, that `expl3` has so easy solutions for problems, where I only find highly complex solutions in `LaTeX2e` based on `keyval`-package or definition of useless commands as in my try.

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing you need to do is replace `\luastring` with `\luastringN` -- the `N` stands for "perform NO expansion" -- in the definition of the `\main` macro. In addition, you need to disallow all those gratuitous whitespaces, by placing `%` at various line ends inside the definitions of the `\main` and `\mychoice` macros.

For the following MWE, I borrowed the form of the `dummy` function from [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463746/5001).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' environment and '\luastringN' macro
\begin{luacode}
function dummy ( argument )
   tex.sprint ( "lua: " .. argument )
end
\end{luacode}

\newcounter{choicecounter}
\newcounter{argcounter}

\newcommand{\mychoice}[1]{%
    \setcounter{argcounter}{0}%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
        \stepcounter{argcounter}%
        \csedef{argcounter\arabic{argcounter}}{##1}}%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
    \csuse{argcounter\arabic{choicecounter}}%
}

\newcommand{\main}[1]{%
    \setcounter{choicecounter}{#1}%
    \mychoice{one,{two,three}}

    \directlua{dummy(\luastringN{\mychoice{one,{two,three}}})}
}

\begin{document}
1 --- \main{1}

\medskip
2 --- \main{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Lua can extract an item from a comma separated list of items.

Comment: @egreg - It sure can. My answer was meant to address the OP's opening remark, viz., "In simple text, [the `\mychoice`] macro works fine, but when I try to use it in a `\directlua{}` from Lua(La)TeX, it raises strange ... errors." The point of my answer is that all the OP really has to do is change the way the `\mychoice` macro is called from inside the `\directlua` directive: One has to make sure that `\mychoice{one,{two,three}}}` doesn't get expanded prematurely, by replacing `\luastring` with `\luastringN`. (Getting rid of the gratuitous whitespaces is nice, but not crucial.)

Comment: Thank you, @Mico for your answer, but it doesn't fit my needs. The contents of `luastring` have to be expanded in my real problem, because `dummy` will store these contents and some later function will use these contents. By then, the `choice`-counter will have changed. I will see if storing the value of the `choice`-counter separately will help.

Comment: @Toscho - Ah, I was definitely quite unaware of your objectives. I was mistakenly under the impression that you simply wanted to get the existing `\mychoice` macro to work inside a `\directlua` directive.

Comment: @Mico And I didn't state my objective in that detail.